# Shortening random number generators in Python

Tags: python-2.7, random

```
import random
fooa = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
foob = random.choice(fooa)
```

That is how I do random number generators in python. I think it can be a real pain to make these, especially when there are a lot of numbers.
Is there any way I can shorten them?

Comment: You get random strings. Anything wrong with the output from `random.randint(0, 10)` (or `str(random.randint(0, 10))` if you really want strings)?

Comment: Nothing at all. Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it and give you reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
fooa = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
foob = random.choice(fooa)
```

gives you a random string from the list.

Because strings are sequences, the above is equivalent to

```
random.choice('0123456789')
```

If you want random integers in `[0, 10]` (inclusive) instead of strings, you can also use

[`random.randint(0, 10)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)